# parsing chat logs in python, currently using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html-parsing, chat

I am having some issues parsing an IM chat log using Python 2.7.  I am currently using `BeautifulSoup.get_text`.  This generally works, but sometimes masks interesting stuff. For instance:

```
<font color="#A82F2F"><font size="2">(3/11/2016 3:11:57 PM)</font> <b>user name:</b></font> <html xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/xhtml-im'><body xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'><p>Have you posted the key to <a href="https://___.edu/sshkeys/?">https://___.edu/sshkeys/?</a></p></body></html><br/>
```

In this case, I get the `Have you posted the key to` part, but it strips out the `https:________` part.

Most, not all, the lines are formatted the same. i.e. date time, user, interesting stuff.

Is there a better way to parse this to get the text AND all the interesting stuff?

Comment: It works for me - getting `(3/11/2016 3:11:57 PM) user name: Have you posted the key to https://___.edu/sshkeys/?` when using `get_text()`. Post the code you have so far. Thanks.

Comment: Hmm.  I wasn't getting too fancy: `soup = BeautifulSoup(i,"lxml")
        soupy = soup.get_text()`

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize [`find_all`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all):

```
for anchor in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    print("The anchor url={} text={}".format(anchor['href'], anchor['text'])
```

Depending on how you want to output this information, you'd have to get more or less clever.